# unable to change password server 2012

Tags: passwords, windows-server-2012

I am unable to change user password on client machine. Server 2012 settings are max password 90 days and min 0. Users are getting a notification saying password will expire.

I have tried to change the password before expiry date but it doesnt allow me. I'm only able to do it on the server. But it allows me to change the password on the exact expiry day when user logs on.

Can any one assist?

Comment: Please supply more info on what you are doing and the error messages you are getting. Try also to make your post more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Press CRTL+ALT+END

this is in essence the same thing as CTRL+ALT+DEL, it will display the login security screen where you can change the password, lock the computer, shut down, etc.

Comment: Thanks man...but it's sorted now. Changed the minimum password day to 1 on server.....and did a gpupdate /force.. it seems to be working fine.